# learn python the hard way ex48 [ Memory error]

Tags: python

I have done the code below , ( not yet done the Number&Error scan  part),but the nosetests results told me there is a memory error. I can't get what's wrong..

This is my code:

```
class lexicon(object):

def __init__(self):
    pass

def scan(self, sentence):

    direction = ["north", "south", "east", "west", "dwon", "up", "left", "right", "back"]
    verb = ["go", "stop", "kill", "eat"]
    stop = ["the", "in", "of", "from", "at", "it"]
    noun = ["door", "bear", "princess", "cabinet"]
    word_type = [direction, verb, stop, noun]

    wordlist = sentence.split()
    result = []

    for a in wordlist:
        x = 0
        c = 0
        while x < len(word_type) and c == 0:
            b = word_type[x]

            if a not in b:
                x += 1
            else:
                result.append((b,a))
                c == 1

        if x == len(word_type):
            result.append(("error",a))

    return result
```

And this is the test_lexicon:

```
from nose.tools import *
from game48 import lexicon

def test_directions():
    lexicon1 = lexicon()
    assert_equal(lexicon1.scan("north"),[("direction","north")])
    result = lexicon.scan("notrh south east")
    assert_equal(result, [("direction", "north"), ("direction", "south"), ("direction", "east")])
```

and this is the result:

```
ERROR: tests.lexicon_tests.test_directions
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\sine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\nose\case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "E:\Python\exercises of learn python the hard way\ex48\tests\lexicon_tests.py", line 6, in test_directions
    assert_equal(lexicon1.scan("north"),[("direction","north")])
  File "E:\Python\exercises of learn python the hard way\ex48\game48.py", line 26, in scan
    result.append((b,a))
MemoryError

======================================================================
ERROR: tests.lexicon_tests.test_verbs
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        else:
            result.append((b,a))
            c == 1
```

In this case neither `c` nor `x` change, and thus the loop `while x < len(word_type) and c == 0:` keeps running and running, `result` keeps growing infinitely and consumed all the memory.

I'm not sure whether you want `c = 1` or `c += 1`, but it's unlikely to be `c == 1` because it is a no-op. You didn't make use of the result of equality comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted to make c=1, not c==1. In this case nothing will change and you will have infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

There's another issue, besides the looping problems, whereby `lexicon1.scan("north")` will end up returning:

```
[(["north", "south", "east", "west", "dwon", "up", "left", "right", "back"], "north")]
```

instead of the desired: `[('direction', 'north')]`

We can fix this, and simplify the code, using a dictionary to hold the words:

```
class lexicon(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.word_types = {
            "direction": ["north", "south", "east", "west", "down", "up", "left", "right", "back"],
            "verb": ["go", "stop", "kill", "eat"],
            "stop": ["the", "in", "of", "from", "at", "it"],
            "noun": ["door", "bear", "princess", "cabinet"]
        }

    def scan(self, sentence):
        wordlist = sentence.split()
        result = []

        for word in wordlist:
            for word_type in self.word_types:
                if word in self.word_types[word_type]:
                    result.append((word_type, word))
                    break
            else:
                result.append(("error", word))

        return result
```

Note that the `else` on the `for` loop isn't like the `else` on an `if` statement, it can be thought of as meaning 'no break', i.e. the code to execute if the `break` statement is never reached and the loop runs out.